# How do I read data from the following json file using ajax and jQuery, and store it in an array?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

[
 {"data" : ["fred", "noah", "jane"]},
 {"data" : ["Mallick", "Alix", "Bred"]},
 {"data" : ["Tylor", "John"]}
]

Comment: No such thing as "json file" but to clarify is this a string in a file, a javascript object or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Use `jQuery.parseJSON()`.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

You can then grab the information from the resulting object and store whatever information (I'm guessing the names) in an Array.